# Qual è il significato di "squadrare" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> Il giornale "La miccia", i cui redattori avevano imparziale fede e nella violenta palingenesi sociale e nelle altrettanto violente e avverse forze della jettatura, insinuò che Rogas possedesse innate qualità funeste; insinuazione che dai pochi lettori del giornale passando ai molti che non lo leggevano, diventò certezza, sicché al nome di Rogas almeno   i due terzi della popolazione adulta del paese **squadrarono** scongiuri e toccarono amuleti per tutta una settimana.

Non riesco a capire il significato del verbo "squadrare" in questo passaggio: le diverse accezioni che ho trovato nei dizionari che ho consultato non mi sembra che abbiano molto senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Comment: L'espressione appare anche in altri libri di Sascia come Morte dell'Inquisitore : https://books.google.it/books?id=w1lyDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&lpg=PT32&dq=squadrare++scongiuri&source=bl&ots=OqpW1EUiSv&sig=KfpGTiv6khcbvDzZFP8QL58StW0&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPpfnR8YnbAhULPFAKHf-RCtAQ6AEIOTAH#v=onepage&q=squadrare%20%20scongiuri&f=false e il Consiglio d'Egitto : https://books.google.it/books?id=Qp0QBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&lpg=PT24&dq=squadrare++scongiuri&source=bl&ots=sglW17OYGY&sig=t4PPQVwREUmyV5JwZ_PKS50t3iQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPpfnR8YnbAhULPFAKHf-RCtAQ6AEIPDAI#v=onepage&q=squadrare%20%20scongiuri&f=false

Comment: Penso il significato sia quello di "fare gli scongiuri". Forse un regionalismo o una forma arcaica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Squadrare scongiuri" in questo dovrebbe significare "mostrare scongiuri", nel senso di fare gesti propiziatori con le mani: penso, ad esempio, al gesto delle "corna" alzando, dal pugno chiuso, il mignolo e l'indice insieme. 
Citando Treccani:

> 2.b. letter. Presentare, mostrare

C'è un uso simile nella *Divina Commedia* di Dante (*Inferno*, XXV, 2-3):

> le mani alzò con amendue le fiche, 
>   gridando: “Togli, Dio, ch'a te le squadro!".

In questo caso "le fiche" sono un altro [gesto fatto con le mani](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesto_delle_fiche).

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Molto interessante il riferimento alla *Commedia* di Dante. [Baldassarre Lombardi spiega](https://books.google.es/books?id=vnYNAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=squadro&source=bl&ots=3NB9Nu52h8&sig=mMM23brRQwi4DiNFE7JyfdDPIe4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ2t6Y9InbAhVBM5oKHV2fAU4Q6AEIGTAG#v=onepage&q=squadro&f=false):

Comment: «Il verbo *squadrare* ha tra gli altri significati quello di *aggiustar colla squadra* (a), è conseguentemente lo stesso che *quadrare* e *riquadrare*. *A te* adunque *le squadro* intenderei io detto in vece di *a te le faccio*, per riguardo allo quadrarsi che della mano si fa mentre si costringe in pugno per far le fiche: come, perchè squadrando il rotondo tronco fassi la trave, ben direbbe il fabbro al padrone per cui travaglia, *a te squadro la trave* invece di dire *a te la faccio*.»

Comment: Penso che altri commenti sul significato di questo verbo in questo passo della *Commedia* si basino su questa interpretazione di Lombardi. Per esempio, Bianca Garavelli nell'edizione BUR che ho a casa spiega: «Il verbo "squadro" allude alla forma simile a un quadrato che assume la mano chiusa a pugno.»